# RestKit 0.20 Post Array Json with nsdata

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, restkit

I'm a objective-c beginner and I try to post something to services with RestKit

This is the json that I want to post to web services.

```
{
   "image":"images/cover.jpg"
   "text":"this is a cover pic"
}
```

I will sent an image with nsdata format
image will save a path that I can get an path to show a picture.

Like: ipAddress/images/cover.jpg

I define two objects: TSImage Object:

```
@interface TSImage : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSData *image;

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;


@end
```

This my code to create a post data

```
    TSImage *testing = [[TSImage alloc] init];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/995399_571403339577816_2064708560_n.jpg"];
    UIImage *urlImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(urlImage, 0.7);


    testing.image = imageData;
    testing.text = @"testingup";
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""]; //for security
    NSString* path = @"/image/";




  RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
  [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"image",@"text"]];

  RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:[TSImage class]
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:nil];
    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

and then I try two ways to post data

First method:

```
[manager postObject:testing path:path parameters:nil
            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
                    NSLog(@"Loading mapping result: %@", result);

                } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                    RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
                }];
```

I only post text to server

```
{
   "image":""
   "text" "testingup"
}
```

Second way:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
    [manager multipartFormRequestWithObject:testing method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                             path:path parameters:nil
                        constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
     {
         [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(urlImage, 0.7)
                                     name:@"expense[photo_file]"
                                 fileName:@"photo.jpg"
                                 mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
     }];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation =
    [manager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                             success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
     {
         // Success handler.
         NSLog(@"Loading mapping result: %@",mappingResult);
     } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         // Error handler.
         RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
     }];
```

I don't konw why it didn't post.

This is my [reference](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0) RestKit

Thank you for your watching.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do two different thing here.

The first one is simply posting two strings to server, and the second one is posting one string, one image, using multipart/Form.

Ensure what your backend server accpets.

Comment: actually I don't know why second one didn't start

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the operation:

```
[operation start];
```

or enqueue it:

```
[manager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```